# Git/TortoiseGit hangs after Clone/Check out runs to 100%

Tags: git, tortoisegit

am running into problems with Git command line/TortoiseGit checkout, please see attached images...

**Hang pic :Tortoise**
[image]

**Hang pic :Command Line**
[image]

Have tried usual Google search haul, network settings etc, but am fast running out of ideas on this one. Bitbucket account & ssh keys all seem to be in order, as does linux environment, running from Windows 10 seems to be a no-go for me, as the next step (Filtering content) never starts.

Answer (score 0):

Update - issue was resolved by supplying correct Nexus credentials at logon prompt, rather than BitBucket account. It doesn't complain about wrong credentials, but just goes into a spin in the background with "401" errors apparent when run under debug using GIT Bash command "GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs pull". Hope that helps, thanks, Mark